# How to pass table-valued parameter to a stored procedure in C# using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have code below which is calling a stored procedure to execute it by passing input parameters to it. But on table valued parameter, I get an error:

> Could not find stored procedure ''.

I have stored procedure which has input parameters `empid` and `emplist`, but I'm not able to understand why getting this error again and again.

```
public async Task SetEmployeeDetails(string empId, DataTable empValues)
{
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[External].[usp_SetSP] ", connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pEmpId", empId);
            SqlParameter tvpParam = command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@pEmpList, empValues);
                tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                tvpParam.TypeName = "[dbo].[EmpValuesList]";

                await connection.OpenAsync();
                await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the method from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters#passing)?

Comment: Yeah, the fact the the example uses `AddWithValue` for the parameter is "unfortunate", @AaronBertrand , but at least the idea should be sound; instead of using an `EXEC` statement the OP should define the name of the procedure and let the application know the command type is a procedure.

Comment: @Larnu Yes. My code is from documentation.

Comment: At *least* (I'm not saying this validates the use of `AddWithValue`) when the TVP is passed the values will be converted to the correct data types; a frequent danger of `AddWithValue` is that is will pass the *wrong* data type to an inline query.

Comment: *"Yes. My code is from documentation"* @dotnetfreak  your attempt looks nothing like the one in the documentation. Can you show us the other attempt you made that uses the linked documentation as your template?

Comment: Don't use `EXEC ...` but just `usp_SetEmp` as `command.CommandText`  and `CommandType.StoredProcedure`

Comment: @Larnu I have edited code as per documentation and getting new error now though I have SP on my local sql server.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have modified the code as per your suggestion but getting new error. Code is updates on question.

Comment: `command.Parameters.AddWithValue@pEmpList, empValues)`; there should be a left parenthesis (`(`) prior to `@pEmpList`. I'm surprised that code compiled, if I am honest.

Comment: @Larnu that was copy paste mistake. sorry

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have updated code in question

Comment: @dotnetfreak - try removing the space at the end of the stored proc name. i.e. : 
instead of  "[External].[usp_SetSP] " , try  "[External].[usp_SetSP]" . See if that lets you get further.